# How to create bar chart in pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, bar-chart

I have some data like this

```
Date
2000
2000
2000
2001
2001
2002
2003
2005
2005
2005
```

how can I make bar charts that represent all the similar years in one bar using a pandas data frame?

Comment: How do you define "similar years"?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [2000,
                            2000,
                            2000,
                            2001,
                            2001,
                            2002,
                            2003,
                            2005,
                            2005,
                            2005]})

df.Date.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Plot 1]

You can sort the years in ascending order like this:

```
df.Date.value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Plot 2]